# What is mLeft and mRight showing in hierarchyViewer?

Tags: android, hierarchy, android-view

I'm trying to see my view properties using hierarchyviewer tool.
 My first problem is that my view seems to be invisible although I didn't do anything to make it invisible. 
My second problem is I see to values, mRight and mLeft which I expect to be the padding space to the parent. 
[image]

I actually don't know what mLeft and mRight means. But I don't expect to get a value greater than zero for mLeft. What can be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mLeft is the absolute position in pixels of the left border of this particular view, and mRight is the same value for the right hand side.

It's difficult to say what's causing your invisibility problem without more information.

Comment: thank you, I solved my problem by reorganizing my views. I would give more information but I couldn't see anything causing this problem